# Create new stored procedure using an existing one with parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure named `(p_Overview)` that expects a parameter `ID` and it basically does some calculations, and returns 4 columns with numbers and a total.

I want to write another stored procedure named `(p_Date)` that uses `p_Overview` and the 4 columns. I also want to use the `ID` parameter to do some calculations.

I've started by creating a temporary table and executing: `INSERT INTO #temp exec p_Overview`. Then I don't know what do further.

Comment: You might want to consider changing your first Stored Procedure to a Table Valued Function.

Comment: the first proc I got as is and cant change it. but I understand

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your new SP in order to use your existing SP's results set:

```
 Insert into #table exec p_Overview @Id OUTPUT
```

Usage:

```
ALTER PROC [p_Date]
 AS
    BEGIN

      Insert into #overviewTempTable exec p_Overview @Id OUTPUT

       Select * from #overviewTempTable
       --Do some other stuff here        
    END
```

That way you can use the `#overviewTempTable` temp table and do what you need in your new SP.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you are trying to call a parametrized proc from another procedure. Then this sample will help you.

Inner procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE InnerPROC
    @Num int = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @TAB TABLE(ID INT)
    DECLARE @I INT = 0

    WHILE(@I<4)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @TAB VALUES(@I)
        SET @I = @I + 1
    END

    SELECT ID FROM @TAB WHERE ID < @Num 
END
```

Outer procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE OuterPROC 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @TAB TABLE (ID INT)

    INSERT INTO @TAB
      EXEC InnerPROC 
        @Num  = 5

    SELECT ID FROM @TAB
END
```

Answer (score 0):

From your query what I understand I have implemented this. (on SQL Server 2008)
Please refer below.

-- =============================================

-- Create table student data (stu_data)

-- =============================================

USE [testDb]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[stu_data]  ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[stu_data](

```
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,

    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,

    [age] [int] NULL,

[marks1] [int] NULL,

[marks2] [int] NULL,
```

CONSTRAINT [PK_stu_data] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

-- =============================================

-- stored procedure for getting data from student table (stu_data)

-- =============================================

USE [testDb]

GO

/***** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[selectdata] *****/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[selectdata] (@sid int)

AS

BEGIN

```
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from

-- interfering with SELECT statements.
```

SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
-- Insert statements for procedure here

SELECT id,name,marks1,marks2,(marks1 + marks2) as total, (marks1 + marks2)/2 as average from stu_data where id = @sid;
```

END

-- =============================================

-- stored procedure for updating data from student table (stu_data)

-- =============================================

USE [testDb]

GO

/***** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[updatedata]  *****/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updatedata] (@sid int)

AS

BEGIN

```
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from

-- interfering with SELECT statements.

SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @data table (id int, name varchar(50) , marks1 int, marks2 int, total int, avrg int)

Declare @fid int

Insert into @data execute selectdata @sid;


Select @fid = id from @data;

Select * from @data;

Update stu_data set marks1 = 12, marks2 = 25 where id = @fid;

Select * from stu_data where id = @fid;
```

END

-- =============================================

-- execute update proedure (stu_data)

-- =============================================

use testDb;

execute updatedata 2;